# how to fetch facebook user id?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

i am using php-sdk to create my facebook app. this app has a share button which will share the url of my app on the logged in user's wall. this is share button's code-

```
<div class = "fb-share-button" data - href =
      "http://apps.facebook.com/lifesrpm?parent_id='<?php echo $user;?>'" data - type =
      "button_count"></div><div class = "fb-facepile" data - app - id =
      "253103488174480" data - href =
      "http://fbtest.adoroi.com/sgi/" data - max - rows =
      "1" data - colorscheme = "light" data - size =
      "medium" data - show - count =
      "true"></div>
```

when this user's friend clicks on the link n lands to my app, i recieve the id of the user who shared my link in parent_id.

my question is, how do i fetch the user id of user, who clicks on d shared link to come to my app

Comment: You need to facebook connect the current user to get his/her id, facebook doesn't share that information without the users permission.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is possible to get facebooks user id even if he doesn't accept any permissions of your app.
this is the code for the same-

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

this is an inbuilt function call which will return current user's facebook id in the form of a string.

Comment: p.s:-this answer is useful only if we use php-sdk kit for facebook app development

Comment: You will _not_ get the user id with this if the user has not logged in to your app and given at least basic permissions before.

Comment: i have already done it..n its working..i also cross checked by changing the ip,systems,users,permissions..its working in each case..i advice you to try out urself