# Once a user has shared a post to Facebook, is it possible to track site visits from that post and reward the original sharer?

Tags: facebook

I want to post a Facebook share link on the website. If someone visits the website by clicking on the shared post, I want to be able to track that in order to reward the original sharer.

My request seems similar to [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309509/how-to-fetch-facebook-user-id). However, the question is several years old, and I'm not sure if that method still works.

Thank you!

Comment: You are **not allowed** to reward people for sharing in any way, because that creates spam. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.4

Comment: Thanks for that! Point of clarification: The page shows several Dos and Don'ts. One of the Don'ts is what you were talking about:

Don't incentivize people to post content on Facebook, or give the impression that posting to Facebook will be rewarded. 

**This** Do is along the lines of what I wanted:
Use referral based rewards to help bring awareness and reengagement with your game. For example, you can give free in-game items or offer discounts on game items for every friend that installs your game through a person’s post.

How would I track referral through this post?

Comment: Are we talking about an actual game app here? If not, then this doesn’t apply to begin with.

Comment: No, we're talking about sharing to Facebook from a website. Integrating Facebook into a game app is something I am interested in as well

Comment: _“we're talking about sharing to Facebook from a website”_ - then we are back to **not allowed**, period.